# Error when following RoR Video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rhtml

I keep getting this error
compile error
/Users/dean/src/carolian/app/views/layouts/events.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
/Users/dean/src/carolian/app/views/layouts/events.html.erb:11: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
"jquery-ui-1.8.2.min", "application").to_s); @output...
I have followed this railscasts video and now im stuck as everything i have tried doesn't work. My Javascript files are located in /public/javascripts yet it still doesn't work. The lines of code this refers to look like

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom', "application"%>               
 <%= javascript_include_tag 
 "jquery.min",
 "jquery-ui-1.8.2.min", "application"%>
```

Has anyone got any ideas why?
Thanks in advance
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dean, the first thing that jumps out at me is the fact that you have that broken up into three lines.  I haven't tested this, but my guess would be to try one of the following:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom', "application"%>               
 <%= javascript_include_tag (
 "jquery.min",
 "jquery-ui-1.8.2.min", "application") %>
```

Or

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom', "application"%>               
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min","jquery-ui-1.8.2.min", "application" %>
```

Comment: I think that fixed it if not it was to do with the file names not being correct after trying something thanks.